# Get a string from between two string values

Tags: c#, string, search, find

I am using C# and have some string data as follows:

I have split this into an array so that I can view each of the above items line by line. Can I please have some help to get the contents contained between each of the th and /th tags when this code is viewed line by line?

Comment: And here come a slew of RegEx answers...

Comment: If it's part of a full xml document with a header, I'd use Linq to Xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it a couple ways.

If your data is already in a `<thead>` then load it into an `XDocument`.

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(data);

var headings = document.Element("thead").Elements().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Or wrap them in an element and load them.

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(string.Format(@"<thead>{0}</thead>", data));

var headings = document.Element("thead").Elements().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Otherwise split out the `<th>` and `</th>` with `string.Split`.

If you have each line in a list:

```
var headings = items.Select(x => x.Replace("<th>", "").Replace("</th>", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and hackiest way:

```
var result = yourString.Split(new string[] { "<th>", "</th>" },
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

A better way would be to parse it via a library, such as HtmlAgilityPack.